# How to compare the old value and new value in angular ngModel?

Tags: angular

Here are codes:

HTML:

```
 <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="car.name"/>
 <button (click) = "save()" ></buton>
 {{car.name}} // the init value is "BWM" from Ajax;
```

TS:

```
car = new Car();

ngOnInit(){
 // eg: I get the car.name from here. The car.name = "BMW";
 this.http.get('/data').subscribe(car => this.car = car);
}

save(){
  //  Here how I compare the car.name with "BMW" ?
}

class Car{
   constructor(private string name){}
}
```

**The car.name always change, because I use ngModel.**
**I wanna compare it with first value "BWM".** 
I'm learning angular form .How to use it? or use Rxjs?

I can't accept this :

```
 car2 = new Car();

 save() {
      this.car2 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(car));
      if(car.name == car2.name)
         console.log("the name is BWM");
      }else{
         console.log("the name isn't BWM");
  }
```

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#onchanges

Answer (score 0):

so if you want to compare an old value to the newest add a variable to your input like

```
[(ngModel)]="myModel" #newvalue (change)="changeEvent(newvalue.value)"
```

and in typescript

```
changeEvent(newValue) {
  console.log(newValue, this.myModel);
}
```

hope this helps. find the detailed using angular template reference variables [here](https://www.concretepage.com/angular-2/angular-2-template-reference-variable-example)

Answer (score 0):

I would say using separated objects for this:

HTML:

```html
...
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="inputCarName"/>
...
```

TS:

```js
car = new Car();
inputCarName: string;

ngOnInit(){
 // eg: I get the car.name from here. The car.name = "BMW";
 this.http.get('/data').subscribe(car => this.car = car);
}

save(){
  //  Here how I compare the car.name with "BMW" ?
  if(inputCarName == this.car.name)
  {
    //...whatever
  }
  
}

class Car{
   constructor(private string name){}
}
```